# How are dates in BCE ordered?

Tags: date

The number representing a year or a century gets smaller as we approach AD / CE.

I was wondering what happens if we have an exact BC / BCE date. Do months and days also get smaller as we approach AD / CE?

So, for example, between `500/01/25 BC` and `500/12/25 BC`, their order from old to new is `500/12/25 BC` - `500/01/25 BC` or the opposite?

Thaknks

Comment: Uhhhh.........no.

Comment: I may be bucking the trend here, but I voted for this as being On-Topic. It seems trivial to regulars of this site, but OP is probably not the only one unsure of how to manage date intervals spanning both BCE and CE. Passing mention of [Julian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar) and [Gregorian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) calendars is probably in order as well.

Comment: What do you mean by `500/01/25 BC`? You should either use the [ISO-8601 Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (most likely `-0500-01-25`) or proper US format which should be recognized by most people here. ISO-8601 allow years from 1583 to 9999. For times before 1583 the details should be mutually agreed between the partners who exchanges date values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of months in a year does not change, neither does the order of days in a month. January in a particular year is always before December in the same year.

So, for your example, 25 January 500 BCE is earlier than 25 December 500 BCE.

---

As a more general point, it is worth writing historic dates out in full, rather than using numbers for months.

To illustrate the problem, consider the date `9/11/2001`. Now, everyone will probably recognise this as the date of the [attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/September_11_attacks) on the World Trade Center and Pentagon on 11 September 2001. However, without that context, the date `9/11/2001` would be read as 9 November 2001 in the UK and other parts of the Commonwealth.

(Given the magnitude of the events of 9/11, even most UK pedants don't argue the point in this particular instance, although Brits often have to pause to make the adjustment to a US date format).

For clarity, it is always worth writing dates out in full so there can be no confusion.

Comment: Not just the British Commonwealth. Every country in Europe and a lot more besides.

Comment: So what notable happened September 11 2001 BCE?

Comment: @axsvl77 My point exactly.

Comment: @sempaiscuba Excellent answer (including the confusion regarding 9/11 which I always have to remember does **not** mean 9 November!) The other point I would make is that people didn't  **know** they were living in BC/BCE, so why should their dates reflect our historical convention?

Comment: [The Zork timeline included with the comedy game Zork Grand Inquisitor features the year 0 GUE with the annotation: "As the year zero begins, people feel fairly confident that something big is about to happen."](http://enacademic.com/dic.nsf/enwiki/2008301)

Comment: Pre 1752 in UK the year changed in march

Comment: @Mark Yes, that's the Julian calendar, where Lady Day (25th March) marked the start of the New Year. Although it wasn't the whole UK that changed to the Gregorian calendar in 1752. [Scotland had already changed](https://www.familysearch.org/blog/en/when-did-scotland-adopt-the-gregorian-calendar/) to starting the year on 1 January in 1600. Not that any of that is a problem for BCE dates, of course ...